# How to make a nested dictionary from a nested list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, nested

Basically I have a nested list:

```
nested_list = [['X1',5],['X2',6],['Y1',5],['Y2',6]]
```

And I want to have this dictionary:

```
nested_dictionary = {'X': {'1':5, '2':6},'Y':{'1':5,'2':6}}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Some people do it with an import but I'm looking for a solution *without importing*

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would use a dictionary comprehension

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice. This is not a bad question, but it would help if you posted your best attempt. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) (even if it's not homework, some of the same advice applies)

Comment: is the first letter always going to be the key in the dictionary?

Comment: @Sanders, This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

Comment: @Sushanth It's very similar, but not a duplicate since it doesn't have the "no imports" constraint. Also OP's desired output there is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
nested_list = [['X1', 5], ['X2', 6], ['Y1', 5], ['Y2', 6]]
nested_dict = {}
for sublist in nested_list:
    outer_key = sublist[0][0]
    inner_key = sublist[0][1]
    value = sublist[1]
    if outer_key in nested_dict:
        nested_dict[outer_key][inner_key] = value
    else:
        nested_dict[outer_key] = {inner_key: value}

print(nested_dict)
# output: {'X': {'1': 5, '2': 6}, 'Y': {'1': 5, '2': 6}}
```

Comment: OP is looking for a solution without importing

Comment: @wjandrea missed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code works assuming that the list elements to be turned into keys always have 2 characters.

```py
nested_list = [['X1',5],['X2',6],['Y1',5],['Y2',6]]
nested_dictionary = {}
for item in nested_list:
  if not item[0][0] in nested_dictionary: # If the first letter isn't already in the dictionary
    nested_dictionary[item[0][0]] = {} # Add a blank nested dictionary
  nested_dictionary[item[0][0]][item[0][1]] = item[1] # Set the value
print(nested_dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'X': {'1': 5, '2': 6}, 'Y': {'1': 5, '2': 6}}
```

Comment: You write `item[0][0]` a lot here, which makes it hard to read. Assigning it to a variable would help: `k = item[0][0]`, then you can do `if k not in nested_dictionary ...` As well `[item[0][1]]` is a bit hard to read too, so maybe you could unpack `item[0]` like this: `k, k1 = item[0]` then do `nested_dictionary[k][k1] ...`. If you want to take unpacking to the max, check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using nested unpacking and [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), you can accomplish this quite easily:

```
d = {}
for (c, n), i in nested_list:
    d_nested = d.setdefault(c, {})
    d_nested[n] = i

print(d)  # -> {'X': {'1': 5, '2': 6}, 'Y': {'1': 5, '2': 6}}
```

The unpacking part would be a tiny bit more complicated if `nested_list[x][0]` could have double-digit numbers:

```
for (c, *n), m in nested_list:
    n = ''.join(n)
    ...
```

FWIW, if you were allowed to import, I would use a [`defaultdict(dict)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: the statement `d_nested[n] = i` seems to also update the dictionary `d`. How does that work? I expected that `d_nested` wouldn't impact `d`.

Comment: @KurtKline strictly speaking, it doesn't, but `d_nested` is inside `d`, if that's what you mean. Or maybe you're missed the `d.setdefault`?

Comment: I saw it but didn't understand. So `d_nested = d.setdefault(c, {})` creates a reference to the nested dictionary within `d` itself it seems.

Comment: @Kurt Yeah, it's confusing. If `d[c]` exists, `d.setdefault` returns the value. If `d[c]` doesn't exist, `d.setdefault` sets the value as an empty dict and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be best done via `collections.defaultdict`, but that would require importing.

An alternative approach without importing might be:

```
nested_list = [['X1',5],['X2',6],['Y1',5],['Y2',6]]

final_dict = {}

for to_slice, value in nested_list:
    outer_key = to_slice[0]
    inner_key = to_slice[1:]

    if outer_key not in final_dict:
        final_dict[outer_key] = {}

    final_dict[outer_key][inner_key] = value

print(final_dict)
```

This assumes that the outer key is always the first character in `to_slice`. But if the outer key is all but the last character in `to_slice`, then you might need to change the relevant lines in the code to:

```
outer_key = to_slice[:-1]
inner_key = to_slice[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict={}
key =[]
value = {}
for item in nested_list:
  for i in item[0]:
    if i.isalpha() and i not in key :
      key.append(i)
    if i.isnumeric():
     value[i]=item[1]

for k in key:
  dict[k]= value

print(dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

If using Python >= 3.8 (uses walrus operator)

```
nested_list = [['X1',5],['X2',6],['Y1',5],['Y2',6]]

output = {}
for left, right in nested_list: 
    if (xy := left[0]) in output: 
        output[xy][left[1]] = right
    else: 
        output[xy] = {str(left[1]):right}

print(output) # -> {'X': {'1': 5, '2': 6}, 'Y': {'1': 5, '2': 6}}
```

If using < Python 3.8

```
nested_list = [['X1',5],['X2',6],['Y1',5],['Y2',6]]

output = {}
for left, right in nested_list: 
    if left[0] in output: 
        output[left[0]][left[1]] = right
    else: 
        output[left[0]] = {str(left[1]):right}

print(output) # -> {'X': {'1': 5, '2': 6}, 'Y': {'1': 5, '2': 6}}
```

Comment: Walrus operator is not needed here and makes the code less readable and backwards-incompatible. Just use normal assignment: `xy = left[0]; if xy in output ...`